# This app contains a virus. Please uninstall this app immediately

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services

We received a serious customer feedback. The customer says he's getting the error on the screenshot as soon as he installs our app from the google play store. In all our test cases we didn't received this error once. So I'm really out of ideas, there are no special applications on this device and it's a very new Android Device, so said the problem was not replicable.

Special about the app is that it is build with react-native but actually I really don't believe this should be a problem.

Has anyone ever seen a screen like this or has a hint why this could happen? I'm happy with every point to think about.

[image]

Comment: Have you found out what was the problem?

Comment: Have you found some information about this case?

Comment: No I never found a reason for this. Also we never got another feedback like this. So I belief there was something wrong with the customers phone, like an Antivirus or an adblock-like software, because our app contains some ads. I closed this issue on our side because of low incidents (only one) for an app with ~20'000 installs

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Huawei android 8 version before ,and this is the solution worked for me:

> the solution that worked for me is to upgrade all the libraries you use in Gradle project side and Gradle app side.

this is my answer, please check it for more information:

[how to fix 'The application is infected with a virus' on Huawei or vivo cellphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000111/how-to-fix-the-application-is-infected-with-a-virus-on-huawei-or-vivo-cellphon/61485287#61485287)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25986596)

Comment: @DavidBuck I edited the answer, please check it if this form is good now.

Answer (score 0):

There has been one occurrence in my previous experience where there was a similar report for one of our apps.

It turns out that some of the anti spyware/antivirus programs available for Android mark applications as potential viruses based on the permissions requested. For example permissions of "Making Phone Calls" or "Sending SMS" or "Reading SMS" are considered dangerous and some of these anti virus programs mark such applications as potential virus threats.

It might be a good idea to know from this customer about the any such programs installed on his device. Please See that such programs might have come pre installed on the phone and the user might not have installed it themselves.

In our case we had to get in touch with the company that had built the anti spyware program to get our application out of their list of dangerous applications.

Comment: I already asked this question, his answer was no he has not installed any anti virus programs or anything like that. Also he has the same device as our testdevice so it's not possible that the app is blocked by the device software