# how to fix 'The application is infected with a virus' on Huawei or vivo cellphones

Tags: android, apk

I made a apk with the code written by me.

When I use HuaWei or vivo cells to download the apk, 
the browser show the tip "The application is infected with a virus".

how to fix it ?

Comment: ![image](https://image-static.segmentfault.com/333/677/3336777740-5ccfd57fe307f_articlex)

Comment: likely by removing the code which those devices treat as virus. Which code? - nobody knows, as nobody knows how that protection works

Answer (score 1):

I had similar warning when testing my app in a Huawei device. I just click continue to install. It seems Huawei will treat everything that is not from an app store as virus.
Nowadays we all understand Huawei is a virus itself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, I have an application on Google play store,
and it works fine in all devices, but I had this issue in Huawei android version 8.

I tried so hard to fix it, but the solution that worked for me is to upgrade all the libraries you use in Gradle project side and Gradle app side.

In my case, maybe there was an old version of a library that conflicts with Huawei operating system, and when I upgraded it to the latest version, the issue of Huawei fixed.

Try to do this too maybe it will work with you and good luck.